The Firefox Add-on SDK died in 2017, but people still use the tag
The current descriptive text for firefox-addon-sdk is:

The Add-on SDK is a set of tools and APIs that allow you to create Firefox add-ons using standard web technologies (HTML, CSS, and JavaScript). The SDK includes APIs, a test framework and documentation as well as a command-line tool for creating, running and testing extensions.

The descriptive text is out-of-date. The SDK was set set of tools for Firefox until 2017. It could be said to be still a set of tools for Pale Moon, but I doubt that any (or at least many) people still using the tag know it.
I suggest updating the descriptive text to something like:

The Add-on SDK is a set of tools and APIs that facilitate creating XUL-based add-ons in Firefox versions predating version 57 (released November 2017). Although it is obsolete for versions of Firefox released since 2017, it can still be useful for Pale Moon and Waterfox Classic.

There was a previous discussion (in 2021) about adding a warning to the tag about improper use, but one of the comments asserted that some institutions could still be using old versions, similar to how some institutions might still use Internet Explorer.

"is there a way to prevent people from using the tag for new questions, while preserving it for old questions?" - no

I can shorten that. "is there a way to prevent people" - no.

People use the wrong tags all the time; it is not a new problem. The problem is users don't, and won't, read (they require explicit spoon feeding). if you can unilaterally edit the post, just remove the incorrect tag(s). If you can't, but the post can be improved in other ways, then suggest an edit, and remove the tag(s) at the same time you improve it (tag only suggested edits are not really ideal in the review queue, i wish they weren't allowed personally...).

Otherwise you could comment under the question something like "Can you [edit] your post to elaborate how [[tag:firefox-addon-sdk]] is related here please? SDK addons were retired in 2017; are you developing an addon for a (very) old version of Firefox?"

@ThomA, even if changing the descriptive text doesn't stop posters from misusing the tag, would it still be worthwhile to increase the accuracy, possibly as an end in itself, but also to help suggested edit reviewers? I'm thinking about avoiding the necessity to clarify the meaning of the tag in a comment for every misuse.

If the description can be improved, it still should be, but it's not going to stop users from mistagging, @Nanigashi .

If you do want to improve the wording, why are you unable to submit an edit?

I've submitted the following suggested edit to the tag wiki.
Guidance (last edit Sep 2015):

The Firefox Add-on SDK was a set of tools and APIs to facilitate development of add-ons prior to Firefox version 57 (released November 2017). Although it is obsolete for versions of Firefox released since 2017, it can still be useful for some legacy Firefox forks.

Info (last edit Aug 2018):

The Add-on SDK was a set of tools to facilitate development of simple Firefox extensions using standard web technologies (HTML, CSS, and JavaScript). The SDK included APIs, a test framework, documentation, and a command-line tool for creating, running, and testing extensions. Earlier versions of the SDK were released under the name Jetpack.
The SDK was deprecated in Firefox 53 and obsoleted in November 2017 with the release of Firefox 57 in favor of WebExtensions. Extensions built with the SDK do not work in Firefox 57 and later. Although it is obsolete for versions of Firefox released since 2017, it can still be useful for some legacy Firefox forks, including Pale Moon and Basilisk.
For current information about Firefox extensions, see the firefox-addon-webextensions tag.

###Documentation :

Official website (archived from the original)
The Road to Firefox 57 – Compatibility Milestones



Hum, pity you dropped your intention tp mention 'Pale Moon' & 'Waterfox Classic' indeed, and 'Basilisk' also. // Not sure if "The SDK was deprecated in Firefox 53" is correct, as it worked/works until FF56 (buggy-wise though, FF v55.0.3 (that I still use(d - until very recently, need to reinstall on a new Laptop), oops!) was/is much more stable).

Deprecated doesn't mean "doesn't work", @chivracq , it means that the feature is no longer being worked on and may (or is planned to be) removed in a future version. Or, in shorter words "Don't use this feature anymore, it will stop working one day." The suggested edit, in fact, says it wasn't made end of life (though uses the acronym EOL, which is less "ideal") until Firefox 57; which suggests that it worked until then.

@ThomA Ah..., alright, about "deprecated", thanks... Then, well, 7 years later, the "important info" is that it works/ed until FF56 (which was super buggy because trying to support both 'XUL' + 'WebExtensions', hence FF v55.0.3 was the last stable FF version). Also "interesting info" for current use of the Tag (in 2024+) is to know which Browsers still work with the SDK. ('Pale Moon' and 'Basilisk' are still maintained, 'Waterfox Classic' is not anymore, if I'm correct...). // "EOL" is a very standard abbreviation in that area...

@chivracq, "The SDK was deprecated in Firefox 53 ..." was preexisting text added in 2018, as was "EOL'd" BTW. My (suggested) edit wasn't a wholesale rewrite, just a sorely needed update. Since the edit hasn't been accepted yet, I added it back in the info section. See my edit above.

It actually worked well after FF57, but required progressively more elaborate workarounds to be ale to use it (e.g., only enabled on Nightly, must be an "experiment", must be a Mozilla written add-on). I'd suspect, given how it was handled well after FF57, that it's possible to use an SDK-based extension even on the current Nightly version of Firefox. However, it's much more likely that anyone who would be able to use an SDK-based add-on would just use an XUL-based one, as the SDK is just a wrapper/library for XUL-based extensions, which abstracts-away some of the commonly performed tasks.

Keep in mind that turning off the ability to use XUL-based add-ons was merely a switch that Mozilla flipped, not a removal of the actual functionality (the fundamentals are a core part of how Firefox works). Mozilla themselves released XUL-based extensions that ran as specially-privileged extensions well after FF57.

@Makyen, if there's a way to make XUL-based TamperData work in current Firefox, I estimate there are about 3.8×10⁷⁰ people who would love to know it.
